# How to connect signals to slots manually in .ui files?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qtgui

Since I'm using **SCons** instead of **qmake**, I have no project (.pro) file, and for this reason **Qt Creator** (I use it only to make GUI) refuses to connect signals to slots. I'd like to manually edit *.ui* file to add appropriate connections. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

`qmake` will convert the `.ui` file into `.pro` and then to a make file.  But you still need to run `uic` to compile your `.ui` files to generate the meta objects to allow the Signal-Slot connection to occur.  Also headers for class definitions might be helpful.

Normally when you subclass the `ui` you will connect the signals using `connect` functions to custom defined slots within the subclassed class.

Comment: What do you mean, `qmake` will convert the `.ui` file into `.pro`?

Comment: @Septagram If you look into a `.ui` file it's basically an `xml` file.  So `qmake` will take that file.  Convert it to `.pro` and then `.pro` to a `makefile` depending on the options you give it `uic` will then convert it to the `.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `uic` to compile the ui file as Karlson said. For example:

```
uic yourinterface.ui -o uicompiled.h
```

This way you can generate complete class from the ui files and than you can just plug them into your codebase

Comment: If I convert .ui to .h and connect signals in .h, I won't be able to edit .ui without having to reconnect signals again, so this is not the answer I was looking for :(

Comment: Normally you don't edit either one of these files unless you establish standardized connections like `close()`